# How to use a custom method on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is a custom method on an array not working here:

```
function runTestMethod() {
    alert("method running");
}

String.prototype.testMethod = runTestMethod;


var A = "A";
A = A.testMethod();         // WORKS


var B = new Array();
B[0] = "food";
B[1] = "bar";

B = B.testMethod();         // ERROR 'undefined' IS NOT A FUNCTION

B[0] = B[0].testMethod();       // ERROR 'undefined' IS NOT A FUNCTION

B[0] = B[0].slice(0,-1);        // WORKS
```

UPDATE: the answer is that I'm trying to use a **String.prototype** on an array. My method needs to be **Array.prototype** instead. Despite array "B" containing string members, these are still being treated as array-object-properties not actual strings. The factory method of slice() is confusingly designed to work on both strings and arrays. Thanks to T.J. Crowder for the explanation.

Comment: You attached it to string prototype, why would it be at array?

Comment: This concept may be beyond my limited knowledge of JS. Have I not created an "array" not "string prototype" with 'new Array()' ??

Comment: *"Despite array "B" containing string members, these are still being treated as array-object-properties not actual strings."* `B` is an **array** containing entries. The **entries** in the array (in this case) are strings. `slice` isn't "designed to work on both strings and arrays," they just each have a function by that name (different functions that do similar, but different, things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've put it on `String.prototype`, rather than `Array.prototype`.

This line:

```
String.prototype.testMethod = runTestMethod;
```

adds to `String.prototype`, and so that property (and the function it refers to) is available on **strings**. You wanted to add to `Array.prototype` instead, so that the property (and the function it refers to) are available on **arrays**.

Complete example:

```
// v--- Notice this is `Array.prototype`!
Array.prototype.oddsOnly = function() {
    var rv = [], index;
    for (index = 1; index < this.length; index += 2) {
        rv.push(this[index]);
    }
    return rv;
};

// These are arrays      
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
var b = a.oddsOnly();
//        ^------------- function is available on arrays
console.log("a: " + a.join(", "));
console.log("b: " + b.join(", "));
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/EfIMacaq/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/EfIMacaq/1/edit)

Output:

```
a: zero, one, two, three, four, five, six
b: one, three, five
```

Comment: Hmm this is a bit over my head. I get the same problem if I create array members B[0] = 0; B[1] = 1; -- no strings involved?

Comment: @user3201867: Again: You're adding your function to **strings**, not to **arrays**. So you have the function available on strings, and you don't have it available on arrays. So when you create an array, it's no surprise the function isn't there.

Comment: Yes I think I see now -- if I just change String.prototype.testMethod to Array.prototype.testMethod that is the solution?

Comment: Though now I'm curious why a string prototype wouldn't actually work on "B[0] = B[0].testMethod()" -- referring to strings "food", "bar" -- but the string method of slice() does work on that...

Comment: @user3201867: `slice` happens to be a method both on strings and on arrays.

Comment: @user3201867: There's no magic. It's just that they each have a function with that name available. It's not the *same* function. (That would be possible, of course -- just assign the same function to a property on both prototypes -- but it isn't in that case.)